# Getting an alternative data value based on change selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, checkbox, input

I am having trouble coming up with the following logic. I have two checkboxes and within each checkbox is two data price values. One is the `solo-price`, which I want to use if only one checkbox is selected. Then I have a `combined-price` in which I want to use if both checkboxes are selected ... think bundled pricing.

I am having two issues, both relating to the combined pricing.

-when both checkboxes are selected, I cannot figure out how to use the combined pricing to show up in the `package1-review-price` or `package2-price-review` divs. Basically rewriting the following variables.

```
var package1Price = [];
var package2Price = [];
```

-Then my second issue is in direct relation to the issue above. When both checkboxes are selected, the total takes the sum of `solo-price` and `combination-price`. It shows the total as $46, when it should be $21.

Within the `calcTotalPrice` function, I tried nesting the total commands, like this... but it did not help.

```
if ($('#package2').not(':checked') && $('#package1').is(':checked')) {
        $('#package1:checked').each(function() {
          totalPrice += parseInt($(this).data('solo-price'));
        });
      }
```

Does anyone see what is wrong with my logic?

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/du68ha3q/1/)

```js
    var package1Price = [];
    var package2Price = [];

    $('.product-check').on('change', function() {
      if ($('#package1').is(':checked') && $('#package2').is(':checked')) {
    $('#packages-selected').toggle(100).html('Both packages selected');
      }
      if ($('#package2').not(':checked') && $('#package1').is(':checked')) {
        //Package 1 single Price
        var str = $('#package1:checked').map(function() {
          return "$" + $(this).data('solo-price');
        }).toArray().join(" ");
        $('#product1-price-review').toggle().html(str);
        calcTotalPrice();
        //$('#packages-selected').toggle(100).html('Package 1 Selected');
      }
      else if ($('#package1').not(':checked')) {
       $('#product1-price-review').toggle();
        package1Price = 0;
      }
      if ($('#package1').not(':checked') && $('#package2').is(':checked')) {
        var str = $('#package2:checked').map(function() {
          return "$" + $(this).data('solo-price');
        }).toArray().join(" ");
        $('#product2-price-review').html(str);
        $('#product1-price-review').hide();
        calcTotalPrice();
        // $('#packages-selected').toggle(100).html('Package 2 Selected');
      }
      else if ($('#package2').not(':checked')) {
       $('#product2-price-review').hide();
         package2Price = 0;
      }
    });

    function calcTotalPrice() {
      var totalPrice = 0;
      var tpPrice = 0;
      $('#package1:checked').each(function() {
        totalPrice += parseInt($(this).data('solo-price'));
      });
      $('#package2:checked').each(function() {
        tpPrice += parseInt($(this).data('solo-price'));
      });
      if ($('#package1').is(':checked') && $('#package2').is(':checked')) {
        $('#package1:checked,#package2:checked').each(function() {
          tpPrice += parseInt($(this).data('combined-price'));
        });
      }
      $('#package-review-total').html("Total $ " + (totalPrice + tpPrice));
    }
```

```css
#packages-selected, #product1-price-review, #product2-price-review {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="product-check" id="package1" value="Product 1" data-solo-price="10" data-combined-price="8">
<input type="checkbox" class="product-check" id="package2" value="Product 2" data-solo-price="15" data-combined-price="13">
<p id="product1-price-review"></p>
<p id="product2-price-review"></p>
<p id="package-review-total"></p>
<p id="packages-selected"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `calcTotalPrice()` function. Notice that even though you select both checkboxes, you also add values for `solo-prices`, hence the total was $46 (**10 + 15** + 8 + 13 = 46) instead of desired $21.

Try should solve the problem:

```
function calcTotalPrice() {
  var totalPrice = 0;
  var tpPrice = 0;

  if ($('#package1').is(':checked') && $('#package2').is(':checked')) {
    $('#package1:checked,#package2:checked').each(function() {
      tpPrice += parseInt($(this).data('combined-price'));
    });
  } else {
    $('#package1:checked').each(function() {
      totalPrice += parseInt($(this).data('solo-price'));
    });
    $('#package2:checked').each(function() {
      tpPrice += parseInt($(this).data('solo-price'));
    });
  }
  $('#package-review-total').html("Total $ " + (totalPrice + tpPrice));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can get the `<p id="product1-price-review"></p>
<p id="product2-price-review"></p>` divs to show the `combination-price` in their respective divs? I updated the fiddle with the changes. https://jsfiddle.net/du68ha3q/2/

Comment: Could you please clarify what you would like to achieve?

Comment: Muszynski When both boxes are checked.. I am wanting the prices for each package to display above the total price. So, since both boxes are checked, I am wanting the two package values to use the `combination-price` IE: The two `<p>`'s to show $8 and $13.

Comment: Look at the 7th and 8th lines: 
`$('#product1-price-review').toggle().html(str);`
`$('#product2-price-review').toggle().html(str);`

`str` is undefined there, since you haven't assigned anything to it.

Comment: ok... I added the variables, but still nothing... https://jsfiddle.net/du68ha3q/3/

Comment: I tried to simplify the code a little bit. Hope this helps: https://jsfiddle.net/rpapfqL6/1/

Comment: Thanks. The code I posted in the fiddle was just a simple version of what I was doing. I am having some issues integrating it. I will keep working on it and ask if I can't get it.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: actually it isn't working fully. The total doesn't work and if the products are changed it doesn't work. I will make a more complete fiddle tomorrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138765/discussion-between-sebastian-muszynski-and-paul).

Comment: Here is a fiddle that is condensed as I can make it, but is behaving exactly as my code actually is. https://jsfiddle.net/ofkoxmj7/

Comment: Thanks! This works perfect. In the snippet, you will see that by the inputs in each package I have the static solo-prices. Do you know how I could use the data attributes to fill the place of the static prices? I've been searching all over and cannot figure out what method to use.

Comment: This is how you can achieve it: https://jsfiddle.net/qe9ytvgs/2/
For further questions, please ask them as separate questions on StackOverflow, because we are getting out of the main issue here. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Thanks so much! I made some changes to nest the functions within the product change handler. I was able to get it work within the fiddle, but for some reason in my actual code, package 1 (calendar) section keeps showing as UND. I have tried taking out `#pack-1` from `$("#pack-1 .package-cost").each(function() {` and replacing it with all of the following, but just the calendar pricing is showing UND. `#calendar-box-wrap`, `.calendar-box`, and `#pg-selection` . Am I overlooking what identifier to choose? I pasted more of my html at the top of the html section. https://jsfiddle.net/qe9ytvgs/3/

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not sure what problem are you having now. Please, ask about it as another question on StackOverflow and put there your code.

Comment: I would make another question, but it just a selector issue... I don't see what I am doing wrong. I have tried `$("#calendar-box-wrap .package-cost").each(function() {`,  `$(".calendar-box .package-cost").each(function() {` and `$("#pg-selection .package-cost").each(function() {` ... the different identifiers in my html (I posted my actual html on the last fiddle - at the top of the html part). I believe this is the issue why it is showing UND.

Comment: Perfect! I really appreciate all of the extended help! Have a great day!